# Loop thru the combobox and compare with the data in the database

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, combobox

i had try several method to loop through the combobox, but it won't work...

```
for (Int16  i = 0; cbxrecipe.Items.Count - 2 >= i; i++)
{
                if (cbxrecipe(i).Items.ToString() != Reader_recipe1.GetValue(0).ToString())`
                {
                     //update the combobox;
                }
}
```

means i need to loop through the combobox, to check whether the items inside the combobox is same with the data in the database, if same, it will not update, otherwise, the combobox will appear new item immediately...

thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your code.

try this :

```
 for (Int16  i = 0; cbxrecipe.Items.Count - 2 >= i; i++)
       {
            if (cbxrecipe.Items[i].ToString() != Reader_recipe1.GetValue(0).ToString())
            {
                 //update the combobox;
            }
       }
```